# can not access id based URL while hosting Eg. article.php?id=10

Tags: php, apache, hosting

I developed one php appplication which works fine when i host locally. Eg. I have an URL category.php?id=10, which will give details about the id which we request. I hosted my site on hosting provider portal. When i try to access the same URL, i am getting an empty page. All databases and application links are properly set.

I tried troubleshooting the issue and didn't find any. Is the problem lies with the URL rewriting on my webs server config file? or any other. i don't have an .htaccess file

Anyone help me resolving this issue?

Comment: Probably error 500. Look at the apache logs.

Comment: `fine when i host locally` if local is windows check you file casing, Linux is case sensitiveness.  Also check permissions, error logs etc.  We need more info.  PHP version may be different etc.  If you developed in PHP7 and used new features like `<=>` or the `?` null deal, then you put that on PHP5.x well it's not gonna work out well.

Comment: "***i don't have an .htaccess***" try creating one.

Comment: `i don't have an .htaccess file` that sort of rules out Mod Rewrite.

Comment: I am using xampp for my local hosting and there is no issues. When i host the file hosting portal (godaddy), links are showing empty pages while accessing. category.php?id=10 is accessible when i host locally but when i host the site globally, category.php?id=10 is opening but showing empty page. @ArtisticPhoenix